# Draw a small bitmap above a larger bitmap

Tags: java, android

I am trying to draw something like this, but it is not displaying bitmap 2. Only bitmap 1 (the larger one) displays.

[image: Example]

```
//bitmap1 and bitmap2 already initialized
Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cubemap.getWidth(), cubemap.getHeight(), cubemap.getConfig());
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, new Matrix(), null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, (bitmap1.getWidth() - bitmap2.getWidth()) / 3, (bitmap1.getHeight()) , new Paint());
return resultBitmap;
```

Comment: what is the output of your code ???

Comment: it just displays **bitmap1** (larger image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set image in Imageview

```
imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView1.setImageBitmap(drawUsingBitmap());
```

Using Bitmap

```
public Bitmap drawUsingBitmap() {
        bitmapLarge = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap_large);
        bitmapSmall = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap_small);
        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapLarge.getWidth(), bitmapSmall.getHeight() + bitmapLarge.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
        // using bitmap
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapSmall, bitmapSmall.getWidth() / 2, 0, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapLarge, 0, bitmapSmall.getHeight() - 10, paint);
        return resultBitmap;
    }
```

Using drawRect

```
public Bitmap draWUsingRect() {
        // using rectangle
        int widthSmall = 120;
        int heightSmall = 80;
        int widthLarge = 400;
        int heightLarge = 300;
        Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(widthLarge + 20, heightSmall + heightLarge + 20, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resultBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        canvas.drawRect(new Rect(widthSmall / 2, 0, widthSmall, heightSmall), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0, heightSmall, widthLarge, heightSmall + heightLarge), paint);
        return resultBitmap;
    }
```

I hope it is helpful to you.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Just checked the code and it worked like charm.
Thank You Sir !